# Test functional version of setState

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Let's say I have s simple React component like this one:

```jsx
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { count: 0 }
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { count: prevState.count + 1 }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Click</button>
  }
}
```

I want to test that when the button gets clicked my state increase correctly. This is the test I wrote:

```js
it('should increase state.count on click', () => {
  const component = shallow(<Component />)
  component.simulate('click')
  expect(component).toHaveState('count', 1) // Error, state.count is 0
})
```

The problem is that I don't know how to tell Jest to wait for the state to update. One way I found is to use `setTimeout` but it feels hacky.

Comment: You are simulating the click on `component`, not on `button`.

Comment: Try `component.find('button').simulate('click')`

Comment: That's not the issue, `handleClick` gets called correctly. The problem is that when `expect` runs the state has not yet been updated

Comment: Your test passed for me, maybe try to update your enzyme version (even doing 2 simulated clicks in a row works expecting 2 as count state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You need to use `component.update()`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html)

> Forces a re-render. Useful to run before checking the render output if something external may be updating the state of the component somewhere.

```
  it('should increase state.count on click', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Component />)
    component.simulate('click')
    component.update()
    expect(component).toHaveState('count', 1)
  })
```